# Inserindo múltiplos modelos em um formulário Yii2

Tags: php, yii

Olá Pessoal eu estou iniciando no yii2, e tenho uma dúvida estou fazendo um formulário em que eu insiro dois modelos diferentes em um único formulário, porém não estou conseguindo realizar o create:
Segue o código que eu fiz:

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {
      $model = new Inscrito();
    $modelEmpresa = new Empresa();     
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelEmpresa->save() && $modelEmpresa->save()) 
        {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modelEmpresa' => $modelEmpresa,
            ]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Não está conseguindo porquê? Qual erro?

Answer (score 1):

Na sua action, você tem que usar os metódos [load()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail) e [save()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#save()-detail) para ambas as classes. No seu exemplo, você deu load duas vezes numa mesma classe e save (duas vezes também) na outra. Segue seu exemplo, com algumas alterações:

```
$model = new Inscrito();
$modelEmpresa = new Empresa();
$post = Yii::$app->request->post();

if ($model->load($post) && $modelEmpresa->load($post) && $model->save() && $modelEmpresa->save()) {
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
}

return $this->render('create', [
    'model' => $model,
    'modelEmpresa' => $modelEmpresa,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso eu escreveria o código de uma maneira diferente, usando  [\yii\db\Transaction;](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-transaction.html)

Assim você consegue se assegurar que se um modelo não for salvo o outro também não será salvo efetuando um ROLLBACK.

```
    $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();

    $model = new Inscrito();
    $modelEmpresa = new Empresa();

    try{
        $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
        if($model->load($post) && $model->validate()){
            // ...
            if($modelEmpresa->load($post) && $model->valiedate()){
                $transaction->commit();
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        $transaction->rollBack();
    }
```